# Bootstrap v4 - beta3 flex broken in Safari 10

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, safari, flexbox

my website is broken in Safari 10.

It appears there is no height set for the child elements ? Appreciate any help.

it works on Safari 11 appears as a bug of safari which was fixed in new versions.

I was researching but didnt find anything similar and it is hard to test since I haveo nly 1 mobile with that software and cant run dev tools there :(

Stripped down version with some new info:

http://html.webotvorba.sk/ph/cards.html

When I use the default card component it is working but when I change it to my custom `flex: 0 1 25%;` it is broken

```
<div class="card-wrapper w-100">
    <div class="card-deck">
        <div class="card">
            <span class="badge badge-discount">Discount</span>                                <a href="en/8-building-volume/bedlam-p16" class="text-center">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="./uploads/files/thumbs/bedlam.jpg" alt="Bedlam">
        </a>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">
                    <a href="en/8-building-volume/bedlam-p16">Bedlam</a>
                    <span class="d-block">Underground Pharma</span>
                </h4>
                <p class="card-text">
                    Component Max LMG


                </p>
                <p class="card-text price">
                    <span class="old-price">98.99€</span>
                    <span class="new-price">74.99€</span>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <a href="en/8-building-volume/bedlam-p16" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Detail</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.card-col-md-3 -->
        <div class="card">
            <span class="badge badge-new">New</span>                                <a href="en/8-building-volume/evoke-p74" class="text-center">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="./uploads/files/thumbs/evoke.jpg" alt="EVOKE">
        </a>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">
                    <a href="en/8-building-volume/evoke-p74">EVOKE</a>
                    <span class="d-block">Warrior Labs</span>
                </h4>
                <p class="card-text">
                    Increases TST production for maximum
                </p>
                <p class="card-text price">
                    <span class="old-price">84.99€</span>
                    <span class="new-price">74.99€</span>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <a href="en/8-building-volume/evoke-p74" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Detail</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.card-col-md-3 -->
        <div class="card">
            <span class="badge badge-discount">Discount</span>                                <a href="en/8-building-volume/hydra-p20" class="text-center">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="./uploads/files/thumbs/hydra.jpg" alt="Hydra">
        </a>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">
                    <a href="en/8-building-volume/hydra-p20">Hydra</a>
                    <span class="d-block">Underground Pharma</span>
                </h4>
                <p class="card-text">
                    Suitable for beginners


                </p>
                <p class="card-text price">
                    <span class="old-price">70.99€</span>
                    <span class="new-price">58.99€</span>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <a href="en/8-building-volume/hydra-p20" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Detail</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.card-col-md-3 -->
        <div class="card">
            <span class="badge badge-discount">Discount</span>                                <a href="en/8-building-volume/metha-quad-p7" class="text-center">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="./uploads/files/thumbs/metha%20quad.jpg" alt="METHA-QUAD">
        </a>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">
                    <a href="en/8-building-volume/metha-quad-p7">METHA-QUAD</a>
                    <span class="d-block">Blackstone Labs</span>
                </h4>
                <p class="card-text">
                    Improvement in muscle density and vascularity


                </p>
                <p class="card-text price">
                    <span class="old-price">119.99€</span>
                    <span class="new-price">88.99€</span>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <a href="en/8-building-volume/metha-quad-p7" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Detail</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.card-col-md-3 -->
        <div class="w-100"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.card-deck -->
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: The CSS you're linking to for Bootstrap is 4.0-beta-3, but the JS you're loading is Beta-2.  I wonder if that could be causing some inconsistencies?  Otherwise; are you *sure* about the version of Safari? Safari 10.x should fully support the `card` component; but if this were really 9.x yes there would be issues.

Comment: I updated also JS but it didnt help. There is ios10 so I think safari is 10 as well?

Comment: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/603.2.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14F89 Safari/602.1 this is the user agent of the mobile but when I put it in my mac on safari it doenst look broken

Comment: Since the `flex: 0 1 25% !important;` break it, what is the default value for `flex`? ... For me it appear to be `flex: 1 0 0%;`, and if, try to use `flex: 1 0 25% !important;` instead

Comment: Have you read my comment?